How can I fetch the private key from my local wallet (Solana)?
I am using this code to fetch my local wallet:
const userWallet = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync(WALLET_PATH)));

But I got the following error:
Error: bad secret key size


The file at WALLET_PATH is your keypair encoded as JSON, and your code is trying to interpret the characters in the JSON file as raw bytes. You'll need to JSON-decode the contents of the file, and then pass them into fromSecretKey. I haven't run this, but something like this should do it:
const userWallet = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(WALLET_PATH))));

